# Magento custom customer attribute gives fatal error in search in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, grid, backend, search

I am using Magento 1.9.1.0 ce.

I have below code in my backend customer grid for getting collection of customers.

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')

            ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');

            $collection->getSelect()->join( array('company' => 'customer_entity_varchar'), 'company.entity_id = e.entity_id', array('company.value'))
                 ->where("company.attribute_id =  982");

            ## echo $collection->getSelect();die;

         $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

It works fine when the grid is loaded the first time, but when I search by custom customer attribute called 'company' in the grid, it gives below fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /path/to/magento_root/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 817
```

I think it gives fatal error when it doesn't get "company.value" field in the query. But the field is there in `customer_entity_varchar` table.

I want the grid to be able to search by custom customer attribute `company`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**In `_prepareCollection()` function:**

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('business_company')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');


         $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

**In `_prepareColumns`() function :**

```
$this->addColumn('business_company', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Company'),
            'width'     => '100',
            'index'     => 'business_company'
        ));
```

Comment: I want the search by `company` to work with customer grid, so please tell me how to make it work with company added in collection. Also I commented out the `company` field in the collection-query but still the same error persists.

Comment: is company customer attribute or address attribute?

Comment: It's customer attribute, it's attribute_id is also there in `customer_entity_varchar` table. It breaks when it tries to find the `value` field of `customer_entity_varchar` although that field exists with value.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. Turns out it was issue with the column name passing in the grid columns.

Below is the code for adding custom customer attribute to grid with searching.

```
$this->addColumn('business_company', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Company'),
            'width'     => '100',
            'index'     => 'business_company'
        ));
```

Turns out the field name I was passing was incorrect which was being sent to collection.